# Is there any way to prevent viewing the username and password of a login from the "Inspect Element" function?

Tags: javascript, html, passwords

I have a login page on my website with only one username and password. The correct username and password is stated in the source code within the script for the login. As seen on the screenshot, as of now anyone can access this username and password by opening the source code in the browser terminal and looking through the script. This is a problem because this login is only to be accessed by my employees. Is there any way to hide, encrypt, etc. this login info so it's not available to anyone but me? [screenshot from Chrome terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5lwA.png)

Comment: No. If the code is sent to the browser (which, strictly speaking, you cannot even know to be a normal browser) then anybody can see it. Login authentication must be done in server-side code if it is going to be anything like "secure".

Comment: You may as well have no login than the illusion of security you currently have.

Comment: Maybe not 100% secure but you could use JavaScript Obfuscation, but I would not recommended it in any case.

Comment: Hash and Store the passwords in a database. Never put them in the source code. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: @ManuelMB Using javascript obfuscation as a security measure is a dangerous advice! I can't imagine any circumstances where that would make any sense.
-- Besides: Anyone who loads that page in a browser will have the password visible in the sessionStorage anyway.

Comment: @brad, kca, I am agree with both of you, so I said "I would not recommended it in any case"  